# Rider - Unable to set up IIS Express Developer Certificate

Tags: iis-express, rider

I'm getting a warning in Rider that the IIS Developer certificate is not set up for one of my projects

"IIS Express developer certificate is not set up for https://localhost:44350. This may cause errors on project start."

When I click the option to set up the certificate I get an exception: "SSL Certificate: Certificate setup error: Cannot set up trusted certificate: Certificate not found for thumbprint "[Cert Thumbprint]" in the local machine storage"

When I open up MMC and check the certificates in Local Machine and Current User the Cert with the thumbprint in the error message is there in both Personal and Trusted Root Certs.

I am unable to run my projects in Rider because of this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably the IP based binding for port 44350 was removed by something else, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#ip-based-bindings so you might recreate it.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the reply. I did check the bindings and it looked like it was all configured. In the end I just removed my existing dev cert and used Visual Studio to set up a new one for me and that solved the problem.

Comment: I would recommend to open an issue in the [Rider issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER), uploading the IDE logs there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing my certificates and using Visual Studio to install and configure it again automatically for me. After that Rider had no issues.

Not really a solution to the problem, but it was the only thing that worked.

Comment: how did you do that?

Comment: @MichaelWiles - I removed the "IIS Express Development Certificate" from my Current User and Local Computer (Check under Personal AND Trusted) using the Microsoft Management Console. Then I just ran the solution in IIS in Visual Studio and it prompted me to set up a new Dev Cert. After that Rider had no issues.